How to append data in CKEditor5
I'm trying to add some data "<div title=\"" + parts[0]+ "\" id=\"" + parts[1]+ "\" class=\"galleryPlaceholder\"><p>&nbsp;</p></div><p></p>" with a custom plugin button in ckeditor5. What I want to achieve is to add the data where the cursor is, then move the cursor to the end of immitted data (the last <p>).
Is it possible?
my code so far is:
    this.listenTo( this.gallerySelect, 'execute', evt => {
        const whole = evt.source.val;
        
        let parts = whole.split(' ');
        editor.data.set("<div title=\"" + parts[0] + "\" id=\"" + parts[1] + "\" class=\"galleryPlaceholder\"><p>&nbsp;</p></div><p></p>");
    } );

but this code replaces the existing content, I haven't find yet a function fitting my needings in CKEditor5 docs.

Ok, now I found a way, like:
        editor.model.change( writer => {
            const div = writer.createElement('htmlDiv'); 
            div._setAttribute('class', 'galleryPlaceholder');
            div._setAttribute('id', parts[1]);
            div._setAttribute('title', parts[0]);
            
            const par = writer.createElement('paragraph');
                            
            writer.append(par, div);
            editor.model.insertContent( div );      

            let pos = editor.model.createPositionAfter(div);
            const p2 = writer.createElement('paragraph');
            editor.model.insertContent(p2, pos, 1);
                        
            let pos2 = editor.model.createPositionAfter(p2)
            
            editor.editing.view.position = pos2;    
            
        } );

the only thing that does still not work is the div_setAttribute() function, as a result the html code produced is:
  <div>
     <p>
        &nbsp;
     </p>
  </div>
  <p>
     &nbsp;
  </p>

and the div has no attributes (class, id and title), any idea on how to set the attributes?
